# How to use clickAndHold method of Actions class?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, action

I encountered the following code:

```
        List<WebElement> listItems = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='select_items']/li"));
    action.clickAndHold(listItems.get(1)).clickAndHold(listItems.get(2)).click().build().perform();
```

I can't understand why there is call to method **click**
If we already chose item1 and item2 by **clickAndHold** method, what is the purpose of calling also to click method?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the `click()` is needed to release the pressed mouse button.

Alternative (I got it from https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/actions_api/mouse/)

```
Actions actionProvider = new Actions(driver);   

actionProvider.clickAndHold(sourceEle).moveToElement(targetEle).build().perform();
      
// Performs release event
actionProvider.release().build().perform();
```